# Is there a way to paste at multiple locations/lines in vim?

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste

I use `:copy` a fair bit. So like range `:12,15 copy 20` will paste a block of text from 12 to 15 lines at 20th line. But when I want to paste a line at multiple places it doesn't work. For example `:24 copy 12,22,25` it only pastes 24th line at 12th line. Is there a **plugin** or **.vimrc** setting that can help me achieve this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not aware of an existing solution that does this, but a command could feasibly by implemented. Interesting question!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`vim-visual-multi`](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi). Create cursors at different places using `\\c` and press `p`.

Answer (score 1):

> For example :24 copy 12,22,25 it only pastes 24th line at 12th line.

It is interpreted as a range, not as a list, of which `copy` is able to take a first address only.

> Is there a plugin or .vimrc setting that can help me achieve this behavior?

It's missing, probably, because it's rarely found useful. But you can always add such command yourself.

```
function! s:multicopy(line1, line2, ...) abort
  " save the text to be copied
  let l:text = getline(a:line1, a:line2)
  " sort line numbers to prevent overlapping
  let l:lines = reverse(sort(filter(map(copy(a:000),
    \ {k, v -> trim(execute(v . '=', 'silent!'))}), '!empty(v:val)'), 'N'))
  " now make all the copies
  for l:line in l:lines
    call append(l:line, l:text)
  endfor
endfunction
command! -range -nargs=+ Copy call s:multicopy(<line1>, <line2>, <f-args>)
```

Note that normally Ex commands use a space as an argument separator, so you are expected to type

```
:24Copy 12 22 25
```

UPD.: Added support for an arbitrary `:h :range` specification. Known bugs/features:

1. `/pat/` and `?pat?` always must be closed. That is, `Copy /foo` is not supported, use `Copy /foo/` instead.
2. With a range a last address is taken. That is, `Copy 10,20` is the same as `Copy 20`, although `copy 10,20` is the same as `copy 10` (a range rarely makes sense for a `copy` destination anyway).
3. No error messages (E16, E486 etc.) are given for bad arguments.
4. Executing an arbitrary string may have some unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Clever! I came up with `command -range -nargs=1 Copy <line1>,<line2>yank | for target in split(<q-args>, ',') | execute target 'put' | endfor` as a first shot, but the overlapping was the problem I had

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah, I also thought about using `split(<q-args>, ',')` or even `split(<q-args>, '[[:space:],;]')` to mimic the behaviour in the OP, but a normal separator should be preferred, IMO.