# Yank once then multiple paste

Tags: cut-copy-paste, counting, paste

My cursor is on line 10. How can I yank line 5 and paste to lines 10,20,30,40, and 50?

I know `:5 yank` then navigate to each line and then `P`, how else can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean [Is there a way to paste at multiple locations/lines in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21839/22797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `:put` command](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html?#%3Aput) (well `:put!` for `P`). One problem would be that the line numbers will change as you paste additional lines, so:

1. Work in reverse order:

   ```
   :5 yank | 50put! | 40put! | 30put! | 20put! | 10put!
   ```
2. Or use `:g` with a pattern matching line numbers:

   ```
   :5 yank | :g/\v%10l|%20l|%30l|%40l|%50l/ put!
   ```